# Limit number of class instances with python

Tags: python, class, pyqt, instance, py2exe

Μy Mainclass creates a simple `QmainWindows` like this:

```
class mcManageUiC(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mcManageUiC, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.show()
```

And at the end of my file I launch it like this:

```
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    renderManagerVar = mcManageUiC()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My problem is that each time i source it, it launches a new window. 
I would like to know if there is a way to detect existence of previous class instance in my script (so that I close the old one or avoid launching a new one), or any other solutions?

Also, when compiling my code with py2exe, same problem with my .exe file on Windows; it launchs a new window every time. Could i add something in the setup.py for Windows to not act like this?

Is it possible, if yes then how?

Note: I'm using Windows 7 64bit compiling with eclipse.

Comment: Are these separate processes?

Comment: all was in the same file.py, i'm trying with the def main in a separate file.py, but is this a way to make separate process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this, you can use a Class attribute to store all the instances -- If you do it this way, you may want to store them as weak references via the weakref module to prevent issues with garbage collecting:

```
class MyClass(object):
    _instances=[]
    def __init__(self):
        if(len(self._instances) > 2):
            self._instances.pop(0).kill() #kill the oldest instance
        self._instances.append(self)

    def kill(self):
        pass #Do something to kill the instance
```

This is a little ugly though.  You might also want to consider using some sort of Factory which (conditionally) creates a new instance.  This method is a little more general.

```
import weakref
class Factory(object):
     def __init__(self,cls,nallowed):
         self.product_class=cls  #What class this Factory produces
         self.nallowed=nallowed  #Number of instances allowed
         self.products=[]

     def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
         self.products=[x for x in self.products if x() is not None] #filter out dead objects
         if(len(self.products) <= self.nallowed):
             newproduct=self.product_class(*args,**kwargs)
             self.products.append(weakref.ref(newproduct))
             return newproduct
         else:
             return None

#This factory will create up to 2 instances of MyClass
#and refuse to create more until at least one of those 
#instances have died.
factory=Factory(MyClass,2)   
i1=factory("foo","bar")      #instance of MyClass
i2=factory("bar","baz")      #instance of MyClass
i3=factory("baz","chicken")  #None
```

Comment: @Pooya -- Thanks.  I've actually used this sort of thing.  I have datafiles (~.5 GB each) abstracted in a class which store the data when it's read.  My factory takes the filename, determines if it's already open and returns a handle to the open datafile if it exists, otherwise I create a new datafile.  It works great.  The references are all stored in the factory as a weakref so that my 500mb of data aren't left around after I close the file.

Comment: That's amazing, How do you implemented weakref for your data files?

Comment: @Pooya -- updated Factory example using `weakref.ref`.  In my datafile example, I use a dict instead of a list to store the products.  It's then trivial to check it the datafile is still alive. `datafile=d[fname] if ((fname in d) and (d[fname]() is not None)) else DataFileObject(fname,*args,**kwargs)`

Comment: I tried the first solution, it should work, but, i'm using Eclipse, is it possible that eclipse will create a new process each time ressource the class and forgot about the class attribute?

Comment: @Ennakard -- Eclipse shouldn't matter (If it does, it's a huge bug they need to fix).  In your question, you state "So my problem is, each time i source it" -- What do you mean by "each time I source it"?

Comment: well, there is this run command on eclipse who execute the script, i'm not sure of what it does, maybe it does reload the file.py before running it, in this case that would explain why it doesn't work the way it should. anyway i py2exe my script and the problem is still there, maybe windows do the same(use a fresh reload of my class)?

Comment: @Ennakard -- Are you saying that you create an exe using `py2exe` and then you launch your application and can create multiple instances of your class (even though you only launched the executable once?)  Or did you launch the executable multiple times?

Comment: hi sorry didnt saw your answer. i did launch multiple times my executable, i think it does create multiple instance of my class, maybe i should find way in my script to get runnings program on the windows task manager and launch the program when he isn't running.At the end it should work as i want. is there a way with subprocess?

Comment: @Ennakard -- If you launch the executable many times, you're creating multiple processes.  What you're looking for is a daemon of sorts (I think).  I don't know how to do that sort of thing though.

Comment: @mgilson -- Ok, thank you for your time and your help, i should fine a way. my script use a tcpSocket, i think the easyest way now should be to tell the server to send a command which close any program whith the same computer name. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of instances you want to create in your code just by adding a counter:

```
class A(object):
 ins = 0 # This is a static counter
 def __init__(self):
  if A.ins >= 1: # Check if the number of instances present are more than one. 
   del self
   print "Failed to create another instance" #if > 1, del self and return.
   return
  A.ins += 1
  print "Success",str(self)
```

Try running via:

```
lst = []
for i in range(1,101):
 a=A()
 lst.append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could monopolize a socket

```
import socket
try:    
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except:
    "Network Error!"

s.settimeout(30)
try:
    s.connect(('localhost' , 123))
except:
    "could not open...already in use socket(program already running?)"
```

no idea if this is a good method but I have used it in the past and it solves this problem

this was designed to prevent launching a program when it was already running not from launching a new window from within a single script that is spawning several windows...

Comment: why -1? please comment with the major shortcomings if you are going to give me a negative score... this will work for even frozen instances using py2exe ... granted you need to pick a port that is typically open   ...\[edit\]

ahh i didnt notice that he was launching multiple instances from within the same script ... in that case  I am sure there are better ways of doing it

Comment: could work, but sockets are bad in windows 7, u have to add a rule to the firewall in order to use each socket you want.

Comment: there are a handful that are open by default ... If you pick one of them than you are fine(the one I used was 3322466) and from your localhost there are more open than from an external connection

Answer (score 0):

Use a class variable:

```
class mcManageUiC(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    singleton = None
    def __init__(self):
        if not mcManageUiC.singleton: #if no instance yet
            super(mcManageUiC, self).__init__()

            self.initUI()
            ...
            mcManageUiC.singleton = self
        else: 
            ...


    def initUI(self):
        self.show()
```