# Creating single-instance exe using py2exe

Tags: python, dropbox, py2exe

I have created an exe using py2exe. However, I am able to open multiple instances of my exe. How do I ensure that only one instance of the exe is running at a time. I notice that dropbox has achieved this using py2exe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [limit number of class instances whith python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458477/limit-number-of-class-instances-whith-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution that finally worked. The mutex that is available in pywin32 does exactly what is required.

```
from win32event import CreateMutex
from win32api import CloseHandle, GetLastError
from winerror import ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS

class singleinstance:
    """ Limits application to single instance """

    def __init__(self):
        self.mutexname = "testmutex_{D0E858DF-985E-4907-B7FB-8D732C3FC3B9}"
        self.mutex = CreateMutex(None, False, self.mutexname)
        self.lasterror = GetLastError()

    def aleradyrunning(self):
        return (self.lasterror == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)

    def __del__(self):
        if self.mutex:
            CloseHandle(self.mutex)
```